# How to invoke an event when a text box loses focus in nsis

Tags: textbox, nsis

I want to invoke an event when the text box loses focus in nsis installer,so that I can execute a functionality when the event in invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nsDialogs does not support this event, you would usually use the OnChange event to update other parts of the UI.

If you absolutely have to do this you can use a timer:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom MyPageCreate
Page InstFiles

Var MyEdit
Var LastFocus

Function MyEditLostFocus
System::Call KERNEL32::GetTickCount()i.r0
SendMessage $9 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:MyEditLostFocus, tick=$0"
FunctionEnd

Function DetectFocusTimerHack
System::Call 'USER32::GetFocus()i.r0'
${If} $0 <> $MyEdit
${AndIf} $LastFocus = $MyEdit
    Push $0
    Call MyEditLostFocus
    Pop $0
${EndIf}
StrCpy $LastFocus $0
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 0 30u 100% 20u "Hello"
Pop $MyEdit

${NSD_CreateText} 0 60u 100% 20u "World"
Pop $9

${NSD_CreateTimer} DetectFocusTimerHack 333
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd
```